# Ruby gets method throws an exception when arguments are passed from the console

Tags: ruby, shell, command-line, argv, gets

I have experienced some ODD behavior from the code below:

```
require 'CSV'

$DEBUG = ARGV.empty? ? false : ARGV[0] #Global debug flag.

class PhoneBook
  #class code here etc etc
end

PhoneBook.start_dir = "file-io-samples/phonebooks/"
puts "Enter a phonebook!"
name = gets #This is the problem.
puts "Using #{name}.."
```

When I pass true to have `$DEBUG` set to true on execution I get an error from `name = gets` and I have no idea why. If I don't pass parameters via the command line everything works fine.

This is the error output:

```
C:\Pickaxe>ruby PhoneBook.rb
Enter a phonebook!
Hurrah! Works
Using Hurrah! Works
..

C:\Pickaxe>ruby PhoneBook.rb true
Enter a phonebook!
Exception `Errno::ENOENT' at PhoneBook.rb:62 - No such file or directory - true
PhoneBook.rb:62:in `gets': No such file or directory - true (Errno::ENOENT)
        from PhoneBook.rb:62:in `gets'
        from PhoneBook.rb:62:in `<main>'

C:\Pickaxe>
```

If I need to I can post the class definition, but I don't think it's part of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gets` reads from stdin if no arguments are passed, and from the file that was passed as an argument otherwise. You are passing an argument `true`, ergo `gets` tries to read from a file named `true`, which apparently doesn't exist.

This is the very first sentence of the documentation of `gets`:

> Returns (and assigns to `$_`) the next line from the list of files in `ARGV` (or `$*`)

Answer (score 1):

This wouldn't cause a problem on *nix, but I expect Windows, or Ruby on Windows, isn't handling the additional command-line parameter the same way. On *nix, we can use `--` between the script name and the parameter to tell the OS not to pass the parameter as a flag. In other words, Ruby wouldn't see `true`, your script would.

```
ruby some_script.rb -- options
```

But, in general, I think you're doing it wrong and recommend handling your command-line options in a standard way by using the [OptionParser](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/optparse/rdoc/OptionParser.html) class:

```
require 'optparse'

OptionParser.new do |opt|
  opt.on('-d', '--[no-]debug') { |o| $DEBUG = o }
end.parse!

puts $DEBUG
```

Running that several times on my Mac OS system, with different parameters, gives me:

```
$ ruby test.rb
false
$ ruby test.rb --no-debug
false
$ ruby test.rb -d
true
$ ruby test.rb --debug
true
```

You might still have to use `--` to tell the OS and called app which parameters belong to what.

Comment: +1 for OptionParser suggestion. I figured it out though. Upon more reasearch gets naturally searches for ARGV arguments to fetch files in the arguments. I had to use $stdin.gets too. Should be the same as on *nix